# Can't rm directory in /mnt

Tags: raspberry-pi

read a bunch of posts about similar issues but can't get it working.

I mount a folder on my RPi that sits on my Hackintosh. I use it for backup. Lately I keep getting this error:
[image]

I have set the permissions to 777 but still no go:
[image]

Any suggestions on where to begin? Thanks for your help!

Edit: I'm sorry, I didnt realize I shouldnt insert images. Took me a few min to edit it. Here is the code in the script I run via cron:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mount.cifs //10.0.2.20/"RPi Backup" /mnt/netbackup -o 
user=xxxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxx umask=000sudo             
/usr/local/bin/raspiBackup.sh
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what is in backup.sh.

Comment: please don't post images of text, for various reasons, see: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: A better idea is to put the commands, script, output and other such directly in the question. You can edit it freely - and should when there's new or changed info. Enclosing those in the curly brackets `{}` keeps formatting readable.

Comment: You're missing write permissions on your `pi` inside of `/mnt`, only root has permission to write, everything else can only read & exec it.
`sudo chmod +w /mnt` fixes it, but its not normal to have write permissions inside of `/mnt`. a more conventional answer would be logging into to the pi as a user who owns `/mnt`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I did try to chmod /mnt but no luck. I think I can only log in as pi (or use sudo -i). It does say root owns the folder but still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/mnt/netbackup` is a CIFS/SMB network share. That means the remote server that is sharing it to you has the ultimate access control authority: even though your `mount` command says `umask=000`, it cannot override server-side settings.

It appears that the specified user `xxxxxxxx` currently has no permissions to write to `//10.0.2.20/"RPi Backup"`. This is something you'll need to fix at the system that has the IP address 10.0.2.20. There is nothing you can do on the RPi side.

When connecting to a CIFS/SMB share like this, all access to the network share will happen as the user specified in the `mount` command. So even though you may be `root` on the RPi, on the network share you will only be able to access the things user `xxxxxxxx` on server 10.0.2.20 has access to.